# Topological Quantum Field Theory with Symmetries and Knot Quandles

Tags: symmetry, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory, category-theory

It is [well known](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104178138) that Chern-Simons theory provides an intrinsically three dimensional way to compute knot invariants like the Jones Polynomial. 3D TQFTs also have an algebraic description in terms of [modular tensor categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/modular+tensor+category). If we have a 3D TQFT with a global symmetry $G$, then we can couple it to background gauge fields of $G$. The algebraic description which includes information about the braiding and fusion of symmetry defects is a [$G$-crossed braided modular tensor category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%24G%24-crossed+braided+fusion+category).

When we have a braiding between two anyons $a$ and $b$, the diagram can be resolved using the $R_{a,b}$ matrix. We can also define an $R$-matrix for the braiding of two symmetry defects labelled by $a_g$ and $b_g$ (see equation (247) of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.4540) for the diagrammatic description). However, note that in 3D, $a_g$ and $b_g$ are supported on co-dimension 1 surfaces, and when they braid there is an extra group action on the labels. This looks very much like the definition of a [knot quandle](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404982900779).

So is it right to say that computing correlation functions of background gauge fields of $3D$ TQFTs is the intrinsically 3D way of computing knot quandles?